# Ask about REGEX on PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

I want this string:

```
{"48":"KAPAL GAGAK"}
```

to become `KAPAL GAGAK` using `regex`. I achieved this using

```
/["0-9{:}]
```

but using this in

```
{"51":"KAPAL GLORY / EX PAN MARINE 2"}
```

resulted in `KAPAL GLORY / EX PAN MARINE` instead of `KAPAL GLORY / EX PAN MARINE 2` because the `regex` filtered all number from 0 to 9.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string looks like [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)

I would suggest using http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = '{"51":"KAPAL GLORY / EX PAN MARINE 2"}';
$array = json_decode( $json, true );
var_dump( current( $array ) ); // string(29) "KAPAL GLORY / EX PAN MARINE 2"
```

*Do add error handling of your choice.*

Comment: `string(number)` is from function `var_dump` if you do just `echo` then just string itself be printed out

Comment: instead of `var_dump( current( $array ) );` do `echo current( $array );`

Comment: Guys. You are awesome! Solved.

Comment: For reference, your string would be an "object" when decoded, the second parameter of `json_decode` forces the output as an array, in which I'm selecting the first value of via `current` to avoid the need to select the value by your ID of 51. As long as your string format doesn't change, this code will be fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
$tests = ['{"48":"KAPAL GAGAK"}', '{"51":"KAPAL GLORY / EX PAN MARINE 2"}', 'not pass throught'];

foreach($tests as $test){
    // json_decode way
    $obj = json_decode($test, true);
    if($obj){
        echo array_values($obj)[0]."\n";
    }

    // preg_match way
    preg_match('/"([^"]*)"}/', $test, $matches);
    if($matches){
        echo $matches[1]."\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some explanation